# Where do I specify that certain planning entities are immutable?

Tags: drools, drools-planner

I am making a (2X2) Sudoku game and I need to **complete** a puzzle. That means that some digits are immutable (they cannot be moved out of place.

In a 2X2 game, there are 16 `Digit`s. The problem facts are `row`s, `column`s and `block`s (get it?). The `row` is the only planning variable.

I specified `boolean fixed` as attribute for `Digit`. But (as per the user guide), I found no place to implement it.

What are the ways to actually make some planning entities immutable?

---

I find these methods:

1. Implement a `moveFactory` that changes the `row` only if it is immutable. This method is **not documented**.
2. If the `row` is not equal to a `fixed_row`, break a hard constraint.
3. Use `@ValueRangeFromPlanningProperty`. Let the immutable entities have a `value_range` of a single element, and the mutable entities have have a list that excludes the fixed rows. This seems unsustainable for anything larger than a Sudoku project, right? And there are (my?) alleged pitfalls that derail the solver?

---

**Extra question**: is method #3 the recommended way for something like a timetabling problem (allocate subject-teacher to a possible period)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 4:
The fixed digits are problem facts: instances of a class that does not have a @PlanningEntity annotation.
The non-fixed digits are planning entities: instances of a class that does have a @PlanningEntity.

If you'd like to reuse the same class for both for design purposes:

1. A custom MoveFactory would be the way. Writing a custom move factory is documented: it's just a matter adding an if statement to excluding moves that change a fixed digit.
2. In that case it's not a build-in hard constraint but a normal hard constraint, I wouldn't recommend that for this use case. See manual info about "build-in hard constraints"
3. Overkill, but it would work :)

Option 5: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3359

Comment: Could you elaborate on (what you call) option 4? Are the `FixedDigit`s identical to the regular ones, except for the `@PlanningEntity`? I (have always) assumed that you place 'planning entities' into one of the 'problem fact' classes. And of course, I would **prefer** that the same class is reused, for easy object-oriented reasoning. While I am glad that all options theoretically works, which one leads to a clean solution, in your opinion? And was that issue created in response to this question? :)

Comment: The cleanest way is probably 5 (uses the same class), but that's not supported yet :( The idea is that you have a boolean getter on your planning entity that returns whether or not the entity can be changed. This would be very useful for repeated window planning and real-time planning (see manual), where users often want to "lock-in" certain entities. Meanwhile, I 'd recommend 4: create FixedDigit extend Digit and PlannableDigit extends Digit and annotated PlannableDigit with @PlanningEntity etc.

Comment: all rules in my complete program involve two members of the same class; two digits in this case : `when d1:Digit(..) d2:Digit(..)`then..`. As per your suggestion, now I have to make rules that involve digit-digit and digit-fixed digit interactions, doubling the number of rules. Where did I miss your point?

Comment: Both of them extend the abstract class Digit and the rules apply to Digit :)